# find distribution of $X_i/Y$ when $Y = \sum X_i$ and $X_i \sim_{\text{i.i.d}} Exp(1)$ for $i \in \{1,...,n\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I know that by calculating the moment generating function, $Y \sim Gamma(n,1)$, and I'm suppose to use the Jacobian to calculate the transformation, but I don't know what the joint distribution of $f_{X_i,Y}$ is because they are not dependent.

It is then required to prove that for $V = \{X_1/Y, ..., X_n/Y\} $, $V$ is independent from $Y$ and $V$ is uniformly distributed on the set $\{ \sum v_i \leq 1, v_i \geq 0\}$

##### Clarification:

V is a vector, where we need to prove that all valid vector (i.e. the set of Vs) are uniformly distributed within the space defined by the constraint that the sum of all components of the vector is less than or equal to 1 and all components are positive.

Comment: What about taking $X=X_i$ and $W=Y-X$. Then $X,W$ are independent.

Comment: I later need to prove that for $V = {X_1/Y, ..., X_n/Y} $, $V$ is independent from $Y$ and $V$ is uniformly distributed on the set $\{ \sum v_i \leq 1, v_i \geq 0\}$

Comment: One glitch in your plan is that with probability $1$, the sum of the $V_i$ is $1$.

Comment: $V$ is a set? Or it is a vector?

Comment: @Masacroso V is a vector, where we need to prove that all valid vector (i.e. the set of Vs) are uniformly distributed within the space defined by the constraint that the sum of all components of the vector is less than or equal to 1 and all components are positive.

Comment: The distribution of the vector $\left(\frac{X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right)_{1\le i\le n-1}$ is a particular case of the Dirichlet distribution. See the construction [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36093/119261) and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Special_cases.